# Symofny2 Get a listing of available Logical Controller Names

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I need to show a choice with a list of all available controllers as Logical Controller Names `AcmeBundle:ControllerName:ActionName`

I see that CLI command `php app/console router:debug` dumps a similar listing, but with controller names, e.g. `fos_user_security_login`.

How can I ask Symfony for their Logical Controller Name representation?

Thanks!

Comment: may this help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610638/symfony2-a-way-to-get-all-controllers-of-a-bundle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hous said, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610638/symfony2-a-way-to-get-all-controllers-of-a-bundle) was useful, but incomplete and its accepted answer misleading.

**A) Getting the controllers**

With this code I get all controllers, but with their `FQCN::method` or `service:method` notation.

```
// in a Controller.
$this->container->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->all()
```

**Some Background**

The previous method will return a big array of routes. Follows one key => value:

```
'admin_chacra' => // route name
  object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Route)[1313]
    ...
    private 'defaults' => 
      array (size=1)
        '_controller' => string 'Application\ColonizacionBundle\Controller\ChacraController::indexAction' (length=71)
```

The `FQCN::method` notation is the right argument to the build method of [ControllerNameParser](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Controller/ControllerNameParser.php)::build(). The service notation is not parsed, as it gets handled by the following code in [ControllerResolver](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Controller/ControllerResolver.php)::createController()`

```
        $count = substr_count($controller, ':');
        if (2 == $count) {
            // controller in the a:b:c notation then
            /* @var $this->parser ControllerNameParser parse() is the oposite of build()*/
            $controller = $this->parser->parse($controller);
        } elseif (1 == $count) {
            // controller in the service:method notation
            list($service, $method) = explode(':', $controller, 2);

            return array($this->container->get($service), $method);
        } else {
            throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Unable to parse the controller name "%s".', $controller));
        }
```

**B) Generating Logical Controller Names**

So all I have to do is filter out the controllers I don't want, {FOS; framework's; etc} and feed `build()` with each selected one. E.g. by selecting only the _controller attributes that matches my bundles namespace `Application\*Bundle` in my case.

Here's the build docBlock

```
/**
 * Converts a class::method notation to a short one (a:b:c).
 *
 * @param string $controller A string in the class::method notation
 *
 * @return string A short notation controller (a:b:c)
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException when the controller is not valid or cannot be found in any bundle
 */
```

**My Implementation**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser;

class ActivityRoleControllerType extends AbstractType
{
...
/**
 * Controller choices
 * 
 * @var array
 */
private static $controllers = array();

/**
 * Controller Name Parser
 * 
 * @var ControllerNameParser
 */
private $parser;

/**
 * expects the service_container service
 */
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->parser = new ControllerNameParser($container->get('kernel'));
    self::$controllers = $this->getControllerLogicalNames(
            $container->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->all(), $this->parser
        );
}

/**
 * Creates Logical Controller Names for all controllers under \Application\* 
 * namespace.
 * 
 * @param Route[]              $routes The routes to iterate through.
 * @param ControllerNameParser $parser The Controller Name parser.
 * 
 * @return array the ChoiceType choices compatible  array of Logical Controller Names.
 */
public function getControllerLogicalNames(array $routes, ControllerNameParser $parser)
{
    if (! empty(self::$controllers)) {
        return self::$controllers;
    }

    $controllers = array();
    /* @var $route \Symfony\Component\Routing\Route */
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $controller = $route->getDefault('_controller')
        if (0 === strpos($controller, 'Application\\')) {
            try {
                $logicalName = $parser->build($controller);
                $controllers[$logicalName] = $logicalName;
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $exc) {
                // Do nothing, invalid names skiped
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    asort($controllers);
    return $controllers;
}
}
```