# Read controllers custom annotations from a custom Command in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I have created custom annotations to generate JSON files (for NodeRed if you ask...) and i'm testing them successfully from a dummy method in a dummy controller.

I would like to port all that to a **custom Sf command** whose job would be to read all Controllers annotations in my bundle and achieve the same result (aka create JSON files).

How could i achieve that ? Would looping through XxxxController.php file(s) with the finder be a good option ? *Or  am too ambitious ? :p*

**Annotation example:**

```
/**
 * @NodeRedFlows(
 *     triggerBy="testFlow", options={"interval":"45"}  
 * )
 */
 public function indexAction() { /*...*/ }
```

Sorry its not easy to post some more code because i have the whole reader class, the annotation class and another class creating JSON flows based on the `triggerBy="testFlow"` id.

**Bottom line:***

I would like to be able to create my JSON flow file from a Command instead of here in my Controller (used it for tests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load all controller actions, which have been assigned a route in Symfony (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943780/symfony2-get-list-of-all-routes-of-a-controller) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610638/symfony2-a-way-to-get-all-controllers-of-a-bundle)).

Then load the annotations for every found controller action:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$annotationReader = new AnnotationReader();
$routes = $this->container->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->all();
$this->container->set('request', new Request(), 'request');

foreach ($routes as $route => $param) {
    $defaults = $params->getDefaults();

    if (isset($defaults['_controller'])) {
         list($controllerService, $controllerMethod) = explode(':', $defaults['_controller']);
         $controllerObject = $this->container->get($controllerService);
         $reflectedMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($controllerObject, $controllerMethod);

         // the annotations
         $annotations = $annotationReader->getMethodAnnotations($reflectedMethod );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need all controller methods, including those without the `@Route` annotation, then I would do what you suggest in your question:

```
// Load all registered bundles
$bundles = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');

foreach ($bundles as $name => $class) {
    // Check these are really your bundles, not the vendor bundles
    $bundlePrefix = 'MyBundle';
    if (substr($name, 0, strlen($bundlePrefix)) != $bundlePrefix) continue;

    $namespaceParts = explode('\\', $class);
    // remove class name
    array_pop($namespaceParts);
    $bundleNamespace = implode('\\', $namespaceParts);
    $rootPath = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../src/';
    $controllerDir = $rootPath.$bundleNamespace.'/Controller';

    $files = scandir($controllerDir);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        list($filename, $ext) = explode('.', $file);
        if ($ext != 'php') continue;

        $class = $bundleNamespace.'\\Controller\\'.$filename;
        $reflectedClass = new \ReflectionClass($class);

        foreach ($reflectedClass->getMethods() as $reflectedMethod) {
            // the annotations
            $annotations = $annotationReader->getMethodAnnotations($reflectedMethod);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the comment don't always have a @Route annotation... Besides, the line "$controllerObject = $container->get($controllerService);" give the error: " You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").". It seems this is going in the right direction thought.

Comment: I updated the answer to address the `You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request")`. error

Comment: Updated the answer to include actions without `@Route` annotation too. I haven't tested the code, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with your first solution, on afterthoughts. It works well (i've change the Reflection to avoid the `You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request")` error but i get double annotations strangely

Comment: Just do `$this->container->set('request', new Request(), 'request');` to avoid the error.

Comment: Got it. I got double annotations because the loop first get ALL routes. And then annotation is again an array...

Comment: Warning: array_pop does not return an array but the last value.

Comment: Awesome - just got it working. You just saved me headache!